# Matrix Commutativity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

**Question 1**

If I have a 3 by 3 skew symmetric matrix, K(t) (K(t) and K'(t) doesn't commute) what would it be

$\frac{\mathrm{d}(K(t)^n) }{\mathrm{d} t} \tag 1$?  is it $(n) K(t)^{n-1}K'(t) \tag 2$

**Question 2**

Then what could be  $\frac{\mathrm{d}(e^{K(t) })}{\mathrm{d} t}\tag 3$

Is it like the following

$\frac{\mathrm{d}(e^{K(t)}) }{\mathrm{d} t} =\frac{\mathrm{d}\{ I+K(t)+\frac{K(t)^2}{2!}+.+.+.            \} }{\mathrm{d} t}  \tag 4$

$= K'(t)+\frac{K(t)K'(t) }{1!}+.+.+.   =e^{K(t)}K'(t)       \tag 5$

So it is obvious that $\frac{\mathrm{d}(e^{K(t) })}{\mathrm{d} t} \ne K'(t)e^{K(t)}  \tag 6  $ as long as K(t) and K'(t)  wont commutate. But is it  correct to say

$\frac{\mathrm{d}(e^{K(t) })}{\mathrm{d} t} = e^{K(t)}K'(t)  \tag 7 $

NB:: I am bit confused regarding this. As per this note [link](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/wood05200431728.pdf), it is says commutativity property of K(t),K'(t). But it never says (7) is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When multiplication is non-commutative, you have to apply the product rule for derivatives more carefully: $$\frac{d}{dt}(K(t)^2) = \frac{d}{dt}(K(t) \cdot K(t)) = K'(t) \cdot K(t) + K(t) \cdot K'(t)$$
Notice the different ordering of the 2 terms on the right side.  This is *not* equal to $2 K(t) K'(t)$ unless $K(t)$ and $K'(t)$ commute.  So (2) is wrong so (7) is also wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is not correct. The linked paper can not state this fact any more clearly than its Theorem.

Comment: Thanks.. I got the  mistake I made now